# Is there any way to explicitly declare int32 in schema in Prisma for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, post, get, prisma

I did an introspection of a MongoDB from Prisma using the command 'prisma db pull'. This detected all number fields as integers (both long and int) and created the following entry in prisma.schema:

```
Index                       Int // Here I search for something like 'Int32'
```

To enable compatibility with 32bit applications I am currently looking for a way to explicitly declare the Int fields as 32bit integers - so far without success. No schema or similar is used in the database yet.

The datatypes for numeric datatypes in MongoDB with Prisma are described [here](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/mongodb-datatypes#numbers-and-numeric-values)

Does anyone know a way to declare this explicitly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Nurul Sundarani [helpful hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435918/9689989), I found some helpful information in Prisma's documentation [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#int).

There is the possibility to explicitly refer to the Int datatype of MongoDB - in schema.prisma this must be entered as follows:

```
Index                       Int @db.Int // Explicit use of the 32bit integer of MongoDB
```

I use Prisma V3.14.0 here [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma/v/3.14.0).

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a column as `Int` would by default mean that it's stored as 32bit integers. If you define a column as `BigInt` then those integers would be stored as 64bit integers.

Here's a reference of mapping between Prisma and MongoDB types: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb#mapping-from-prisma-to-mongodb-types-on-migration)

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I must have overlooked this information. Interestingly, there is still the problem that the integers are stored in 64bit format, but then the error is probably somewhere else.